# Strange "inaccessible value" in debugger

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe4

Could anyone explain this screen:

[image]

As you can see I have simple array - debugger shows values of its elements when I use A[0], A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6feQh.jpg)...
but I cannot get elements with **local** variable A[i]   *(but value of "i" is shown correctly)*.

**Project settings**:
   Debug info: **ON**
   Local Symbols: **ON**
   Optimization: **OFF**.

Project (one PAS file) is BUILD so DCU is fresh. You can see on that screen almost full code of this test project so there is no chance that array A or "i" is declared in some other unit etc...

Now I checked - the same code in **Delphi XE3** works perfectly - debugger shows all values.
It seems that XE4 has a serious bug in basic feature :-((

Comment: check properties for A[i] watch and try to setting "allow function call" there. Just shooting into the skies.

Comment: try adding `j:integer` variable, adding `j := i` into the loop body and watching `A[j]` instead. It is exotic tome (XE2 user) to see i grayed out and i cannot see any other reason, than it being loop-variable. BTW, turning optimizations ON, would it help ?

Comment: Please post your "Project Options" window selecting the "Compiler" item so that we could see the full configuration.

Comment: What does `High(A)` return? I'm not sure how `High` works with associative arrays, but is it possible `High(A)` is returning the highest value, not highest key? If that's the case, it may be trying to access `A[2]`, and that is inaccessable

Comment: I tried to reproduce in an older version of Delphi and had some likely behavior... ALthough, in my context, Optimization was ON. I would like to compare your full configuration (your "Project Options" window selecting the "Compiler") with mine, @rafal-chlopek.

Comment: @dKen: `A` is not an "associative array". It is an ordinary static array. `High(A)` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because 'val' is a function and not a variable. Double click on the watched item and check the property 'allow function calls'.

Comment: It's clearly visible from the code the OP posted, that 'val' is an integer child element (that is: variable indeed) of the record named 'TSome', and A is an array of that record. Therefore, A[i].val is pointing to an integer variable and not a function indeed...

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a var and this var need an amount for instance change i to 1 and check it;

```
A[1].val;
```